# &lt; и символ < одно и тоже в HTML или нет?

Tags: html, кодировка, utf-8, unicode, ascii

Могу ли я вместо, например, открывающего тега `<` писать `&lt;` ? И как браузер будет это интерпретировать?

Comment: Что мешает реализовать и посмотреть?

Comment: интересно, зачем это Вам?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Символ `<` браузер интерпретирует как начало html-тэга. Поэтому, если в тексте нужно указать этот символ, то используется его спецзамена `&lt;`. Но сами тэги должны указывать только как `<`.

Comment: Данный способ реализован в случае, когда нужно поставить скажем спец. символ, но, чтобы это не повлияло на работу интерпретатора.

Comment: Тогда непонятно, как браузер их различает? У них различные байтовые значения? Я думал они одни и те же байты представляют

Comment: @ПавелИгорев `&lt;` это четыре байта, `<` это один байт — совершенно не одно и то же

Comment: @andreymal а чему равно значение этого одного байта?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев этому самому `<` и равно, значение в виде десятичного числа — 60

Comment: @andreymal а понял, точно 3С в десятичной. А могу ля я как-нибудь это представить в виде байта 60 в HTML коде, чтобы браузер воспринял это также как открытие тега?

Comment: @ПавелИгорев написание `<` это и будет именно байт 60 в HTML-коде, ваши вопросы совершенно непонятны